# What is meant by "when the moon is out" in the Silent Moons Enchant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The "Silent Moons Enchant" Enchantment states that it effect happens "when the moon is out", but what exactly does this mean?

To be specific:

- Does it matter where you're located? (inside / outside)
- Does the weather has any influence? (clear sky or not)
- Do the Phases of one or both of the moons matter? (moonlight?)
- Does it use charges when the moon is not out?

Comment: this is definitely interesting enough to test out later when I get home

Comment: Maybe you can add this to your question: does it use enchantment charges when the moon is not out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some quick testing, I have to say that this enchantment currently doesn't work.

I made myself a test dagger with a super high enchanting level so there'd be no doubt of the effect if it did trigger.  It was done with a petty soul gem so I can see the draining of charges very easily:

[image: Dagger]

Here are the results from tests, I used getav health to see how much damage I did with 1 attack:

**Night No Moon**
Indoors - 8 damage - charges used
Outdoors - 8 damage - charges used

**Day No Moon**
Outdoors - 8 damage - charges used

**Day with Moon**
Outdoors - 8 damage - charges used

**Night with Moon**
Outdoors - 8 damage - charges used

As you can see from the screen shot, even hitting Heimskr when there were TWO moons out still only did 8 damage.

[image: TWO MOONS]

Comment: Did you forge the weapon at the moon camp forge? :)

Comment: @GmNoob nope, it was a random dagger I got, I thought it was just the enchantment that mattered, do I have to forge it too at the camp?  UESP seems to suggest you can't craft lunar enchantment weapons at that forge: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silent_Moons_Camp

Comment: No idea, just another thought on the matter.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't specifics, but I received a lunar axe from one of the Jarls quests. I destroyed it at an enchantment table and you can then add that enchantment at whatever table you're at.

Comment: You must make the weapon at the Silent Moon Forge at midnight when both moons are out, then enchant it with the silent moons enchantment. Both moons come out about once every 3 days.

Comment: @Jake and what will happen if you do?

Comment: @yx What version of Skyrim are you using?

Comment: @galacticninja PC

Comment: @yx What I meant was, what patch version? I'm curious to know if this is still the case with the current patch version.

Comment: @galacticninja oh, whatever patch version that was out at the time of the answer, I haven't revisited it since

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's been patched or what, but I do know from experience that you could at one point forge the lunar weapons at the forge without having to enchant them. The correct time to forge was marked by a short charging sound when entering the small chamber, a blue aura around the forge and flames, and enlarged moons. I'd done this not long after the game had come out though, and you were unable to just disenchant the weapon back then. I'd tried it again just recently, and whenever the two moons would finally sync, it'd be cloudy and the forge would not work. Whether this is because of the patch or not, I do not know. My test was quite short however, as I am on the console and waiting around for months on end is rather unpleasant, so it is relatively inconclusive.  I do know that these weapons CAN be forged if the conditions are met, and will retain that enchantment when crafted. As well, the variation that is crafted ONLY works at night, unlike the crafted variation of the enchantment that works all the time, despite the description.